# Is it acceptable to model an event queue as a restful service?

Tags: rest, architecture

I have been looking at RESTful Web Services and was wondering about modelling an event queue in REST.

Assuming the event queue is accessible at URL: http://my.domain/events, it seems to me that a POST operation applied to this URL is okay because it will add the event to the end of the list that represents the queue. Further, if I perform a GET operation on this URL, it seems to me that returning the head of queue also is okay.

My question is - is it okay for the GET operation to also remove the head of the queue or should this be performed by a separate DELETE operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it okay for the GET operation to also remove the head of the queue

No, it is not from REST perspective. GET request should be *safe* according to REST best practices. Making any number of GET requests to a URL should have the same effect as making no requests at all.
There's one more concern about your design. There are usually two common patterns to retrieve a queue head:

1. The first one is to just get a head, process it and then notify the queue to remove the message if it was processed successfully, if not, the message gets back to the queue to be processed later again. It's a more robust approach.
2. The second one is to just get a queue head and remove it at the same time just like you described in your question.

To support both patterns I think you should only retrieve a message when doing GET and implement DELETE method so it returns a deleted message object as a response. This way you will comply with REST uniform interface and your queue client will be able to implement both patters.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Does your integrity requirements allow GET + DELETE in one step? 
Events normally should not get lost. What happens if the response retrieval fails after the delete was executed?

I would GET the head of the queue and then send an acknowledgement containing the event ID that was received and successfully processed. Thus, you guarantee an at-least-once-delivery.

Depending on the number of events you are processing, a message bus might be the more suitable option here.

Answer (score -1):

Do not become an overzealous REST paradigm worshipper. REST is a protocol but it does not necessarily need to convey the contract of the service.

What you say is perfectly fine as long as the contract between the consumer and the queue are clear and documented.